# how to do template class constructors as forward declaration

Tags: c++20

I am migrating my code from c++17 to c++20 and need to use **require** instead of std::enable_if...

How to define class constructors as forward declaration with c++20 that uses require keyword on following sample ?

```
#include <type_traits>
    
class CChMyBaseClass {
};
    
template <
    typename    _ChClass,
    typename    _ChFunction>
class CChMyClass : public CChMyBaseClass {
    private:
        _ChFunction m_ChFunction;

    public:
        // how to do forward declaration ?
        CChMyClass()
            requires (std::is_member_function_pointer<_ChFunction>::value)
                : CChMyBaseClass() {
        }

        // how to do forward declaration ?
        CChMyClass()
            requires (!std::is_member_function_pointer<_ChFunction>::value)
                : CChMyBaseClass()
                    , m_ChFunction(
                        nullptr) {
        }
};
    
class CChTestClass {
    public:
        void    ChTest() {
        }
};
    
void ChTest() {
}
    
int main() {
    CChMyClass<CChTestClass, decltype(&CChTestClass::ChTest)>   CChMyClass1();
    CChMyClass<CChTestClass, decltype(&ChTest)>                 CChMyClass2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try? Did your compiler reject it? It will be very vexing if the moment you receive an answer you counter with "this error happens".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, thanks your comment.  G. Sliepen has already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not different from any other type of forward declaration. Just write:

```
template <typename _ChClass, typename _ChFunction>
class CChMyClass: public CChMyBaseClass {
    ...
    CChMyClass() requires (std::is_member_function_pointer<_ChFunction>::value);
    CChMyClass() requires (!std::is_member_function_pointer<_ChFunction>::value);
    ...
};
```

I think the difficulty is rather in the actual function definitions. But even that is not too difficult if you think about it. You just need to include the `template` parameters and the `requires` clause again:

```
template <typename _ChClass, typename _ChFunction>
CChMyClass<_ChClass, _ChFunction>::CChMyClass()
requires (std::is_member_function_pointer<_ChFunction>::value)
: CChMyBaseClass(), m_ChFunction(...) {
    ...
};
```

Note that in your example, you did not declare two instances of `CChMyClass` in `main()`, but rather forward declared two functions that had a `CChMyClass` as a return type (this is known as the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). Just omit the `()` at the end, or use braces instead.

Comment: G. Sliepen, thanks for your help.  In my real code, my mistake was that I declared the constructure once, cause'f I was think all are the same :)